# SQLAlchemy - filtering rows before today with autoloaded DATETIME column?

Tags: sqlalchemy, mariadb

I have a MARIADB database `radio_progs` with a table `FUTUREEPISODE`. I'm using SQLAlchemy and trying to add a function that selects **all entries in the table that are before today**.

I'm having problems with the datetime field though. Is this as I'm autoloading the fields? In my real world example I have a number of columns so would prefer to autoload than specify each individually.

error is

```sh
    eps = self.query.filter_by(IN_LIST=1, EP_ENDTIME < todays_datetime).all()
                                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

The table has the following columns

```
| Column     | Type       |
| ---------- | ---------- |
| ID         | int(11)    |
| EP_ENDTIME | datetime   |
| IN_LIST    | tinyint(1) |
```

```py
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import and_, func

from .dbmgr import db

class FutureEpisode(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'radio_progs'
    __tablename__ = 'FUTUREEPISODE'

    __table_args__ = {
        'autoload': True,
        'autoload_with': db.engine
    }

    def get_expired(self):

        todays_datetime = datetime(datetime.today().year, datetime.today().month, datetime.today().day)
        eps = self.query.filter_by(IN_LIST=1, EP_ENDTIME < todays_datetime).all()
        return eps
```

Comment: Use a sequence table.  `seq_1_to_100` is a table of 1 to 100.  Use that in `- INTERVAL num DAY` to get previous days.

Comment: The entries in the table could be in any order. I'm looking for a function that takes the current time and return all entries (in any order) before the current time

Comment: `WHERE EP_ENDTIME < NOW()`

Comment: I'm trying to do this in SQLAlchemy. The problem is that EP_ENDTIME is not available to the query. I think it might be to do with using autoload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using filter rather than filter_by works, i.e. changing the query to:

```py
eps = self.query.filter(FutureEpisode.IN_LIST==1, FutureEpisode.EP_ENDTIME < todays_datetime).all()
```